# Not able to register for Salesforce Admin maintenance exam

Tags: certification

Every time i click on register for Winter 17 admin exam it shows below error.

> An unexpected error occurred while computing your tax. Please try
>   again after a couple of hours.

Comment: I'm also facing this issue. Seems this is the reflection of GST. Will see in day or two, if Salesforce resolves this error.

Comment: As you are doing in Forex(Its above Indian Law jurisdiction). GST wont apply here so thats not an issue. Meanwhile you raise a case here. http://certification.salesforce.com/open-a-casen raise a case with SF

Answer (score -1):

I just left the code blank & then selected Checkout. That did it!